# Can't get a screenshot anymore when computer is locked

Tags: windows-10, screenshot, lockscreen, win32gui, bluestacks

I'm generating screenshots (of BlueStacks 5) programmatically via this way:

```py
        hDC = win32gui.GetWindowDC(self.child_hwnd)
        myDC = win32ui.CreateDCFromHandle(hDC)
        newDC = myDC.CreateCompatibleDC()

        myBitMap = win32ui.CreateBitmap()
        myBitMap.CreateCompatibleBitmap(myDC, self.rect_child.w, self.rect_child.h)

        newDC.SelectObject(myBitMap)
        # newDC.BitBlt((0, 0), (self.rect_child.w, self.rect_child.h), myDC, (0, 0), win32con.SRCCOPY)
        # myBitMap.Paint(newDC)
        ctypes.windll.user32.PrintWindow(self.child_hwnd, newDC.GetSafeHdc(), 2)

        myBitMap.Paint(newDC)
```

However, I noticed something peculiar. When I lock my computer (Win-L), the screenshots that are taken are from the -I guess- last screen that was drawn before my lock.

I noticed that a lot of other questions has been asked before, and seems these are resolved by using the `PrintWindow` function. I tried that, and with the magic number `2` I got a screenshot, but it was always the same as the first one. So I'm guessing BlueStacks doesn't update its buffer when the computer is locked to save resources I assume?

I tried this out by sleeping 2 seconds between taking screenshots, and I always got the same one... So, is my assumption right? How would I go about it? Or just run the application in a VM which never sleeps?

How would I go to still get the screenshot? Because the application continues running fine.

Thanks!

Comment: Because the desktop (that you logged on) became invisible when you locked the screen, so the system wonot generate WM_PAINT message for them. I suggest try invoke " InvalidateRect(hWnd, NULL, TRUE); UpdateWindow(hWnd) " first, then get the window DC and use BitBlt to copy from that window DC.